# Cross Apply with Derived Column In SQL with Case Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have very simple query with few computed column like

```
SELECT COL1 , COL2,COL3
COL4 = (COL1-(COL2*.15))
COL5 = (COL3*(COL1*1.5))

FROM TABLE1 AS A 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS B
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Now i am trying to put Case statement on computed column value using cross apply

```
CROSS APPLY (

SELECT REMARKS = CASE WHEN COL4> COL1 THEN GOOD ELSE BAD END
```

but this is giving error .

In Output I am expecting all column i.e col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,Remarks

Can someone please suggest what is my mistake?

Comment: please add rdbms-tag. please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What's the error message that you are getting?

Comment: first try to show error. Second eg. col4 is computed so put the computation into the case and not col4

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement. (It returns a value.)

Comment: please add some sample data and show us, WHAT you want to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `CROSS APPLY` cannot access a computed field from the `SELECT` clause because it is evaluated first.

One option is to cascade your computed columns using one `CROSS APPLY` for each column:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3,
       C.COL4, D.COL5,
       E.REMARKS 
FROM TABLE1 AS A 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COL4 = (COL1-(COL2*.15))) AS C
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COL5 = (COL3*(COL1*1.5))) AS D
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REMARKS = CASE WHEN C.COL4 > COL1 THEN 'GOOD' ELSE 'BAD' END) AS E
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/67076/2)

Comment: Thanks..... will it work if col1 , col2 and col3 are from different table ? Please suggest

Comment: @RohiniMathur Yes, it will work. Just use the table alias before the field name so as to remove an y ambiguities.

Comment: @RohiniMathur My query was missing a comma. I've fixed that. Apart from that the query seems to execute OK. Please check the attached fiddle demo.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
SELECT *,CASE WHEN COL4 > COL1 THEN 'GOOD' ELSE 'BAD' END AS Remark
FROM (
         SELECT COL1 , COL2,COL3
         COL4 = (COL1-(COL2*.15))
         COL5 = (COL3*(COL1*1.5))
         FROM TABLE1 AS A 
         INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
)M
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your first script in select statement then do cross apply

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT COL1 , COL2,COL3
                ,COL4 = (COL1-(COL2*.15))
                ,COL5 = (COL3*(COL1*1.5)) 

FROM TABLE1 AS A 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS B
ON A.ID = B.ID )t

CROSS APPLY

(
SELECT  CASE WHEN t.COL4 > t.COL1 THEN 'GOOD' ELSE 'BAD' END REMARKS
) t1
```

Comment: The Error Message is Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ComparePrices, Line 39
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select x.Iss_Carat,x.Rec_Carat,x.REMARKS from Process_Issue_Receive PTR
cross apply( SELECT *, REMARKS = CASE WHEN Rec_Carat> Iss_Carat THEN 'GOOD' 
                                ELSE 'BAD' 
                                END FROM LAB_Issue_Receive LIR where ptr.Lot_Key = LIR.Lot_key)x where x.REMARKS = 'GOOD'
```

Try This Query  with 2 Diff Table